# Python's os.getenv() doesn't seem to work on OSX Mavericks

Tags: python, macos, google-app-engine, osx-mavericks

In OSX Maverick's terminal I set my env variable like this:

```
export FLASK_CONF=DEV
```

then with `export` I can confirm that the variable is set.

```
declare -x FLASK_CONF="DEV"
...
```

Now when I run my app under GAE: `dev_appserver.py src/`

I get the message that the production environment has been loaded instead of dev environment:

```
INFO     2014-01-15 23:39:41,702 __init__.py:38] Staging/Production Env found
```

This is the code:

```
if os.getenv('FLASK_CONF') == 'DEV':
    logging.info("DEV ENv found")
    app.config.from_object('application.settings.Development')
elif os.getenv('FLASK_CONF') == 'TEST':
    logging.info("TEST Env found")
    app.config.from_object('application.settings.Testing')
else:
    logging.info("Staging/Production Env found")
    app.config.from_object('application.settings.Production')
```

I am 100% sure this worked fine on the previous Mountain Lion. Could it be related to how Maverick OSX is setting/using the env variables?  Any advice how to solve this?

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/tXRAwkEe) is a quick test with Mavericks to prove that it's setting the environment variables and Python (the one that came built-in with Mavericks, but the same thing works with 7 other builds of CPython and PyPy on the machine…) is able to see them.

Comment: So presumably there's something else wrong. And to debug it, we'd need a complete example (see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) that reproduces the problem, not just a code fragment that works on its own but doesn't work in your environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try defining your environment variable in app.yaml using [env_variables](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Defining_environment_variables):

```
env_variables:
  FLASK_CONF: 'DEV'
```

Comment: Yes that works. Thanks. It seems GAE is running under an isolated environment.

Comment: @Hooman - devappserver's goal is to reproduce the environment your app will have when running in the cloud.